# How the democratic voting system in the document is decided?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, governance

What is the default voting system after submitting a democratic proposal?

https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-governance#tallying

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: the default for public proposal is positive turnout bias.

If you submit a public proposal to democracy module (as you show in the screenshot above), once it is up for vote, it will be tallied with a positive turnout bias (super majority approve): this means that, in order to be approved a heavy super-majority of `aye` votes is required to carry at low turnouts, but as turnout increases towards 100%, it becomes a simple majority-carries.

For your proposal to pass you need to lobby for a big turnout: the turnout increase lowers the required `Aye` votes for the proposal to pass.